# Can I get the entity framework to use concrete classes instead of interfaces (for web service serialisation)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am learning about web services and the book I am using is pulling data from SQL server using the entity framework (which I know little about too).

Unfortunately the classes created by the entity framework contain things like:

```
public Conference()
{
   this.Sessions = new HashSet<Session>();
}
public virtual ICollection<Session> Sessions { get; set; }
```

Which causes a problem because an interface is not serialisable:

> Cannot serialize member X of type
>   System.Collections.Generic.ICollection ... because it is an interface.

Now I could (and did) modify the generated classes to use concrete classes but if I ever need to regenerate the entities then that change will be undone. Ideally I could tell the entity framework to generate something like this (or even better, have control of the concrete type so I could tell the entity framework to use a List if I want to):

```
public Conference()
{
   this.Sessions = new HashSet<Session>();
}
public virtual HashSet<Session> Sessions { get; set; }
```

Is it possible? If so, how?

Comment: This has some related discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1333864/xml-serialization-of-interface-property

Comment: It's a bit more complicated than what I was thinking of (I didn't need to use an interface for that exercise) but it's interesting and informative so thanks for it. I haven't had time to look at it in details but I think a code-first approach and mapping to an existing database looks like a viable approach for what I was thinking of: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj200620.aspx

Answer (score 0):

EF code generator creates entity classes as [partial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx), so you may create another code file in the same assembly with some tricks:

```
public partial class Conference
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public bool SessionsSpecified
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public Session[] SerializableSessions
    {
        get { return new Sessions.ToArray(); }
        set { Sessions = value; }
    }
}
```

SessionSpecified property is a XmlSerializer [trick](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/drnick/archive/2010/04/26/optional-xml-fields.aspx) to ignore Sessions property during serialization.
Session[] will be serialized instead of ICollection. Check if it is possible to expose internal EF collection types to use cast instead of copying an array.

**Alternative solution** is to implement [IXmlSerializable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.Serialization.IXmlSerializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and have a full control of how Conference class serialized.

Answer (score 0):

I used [T4 template](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/entityframework/L0EV220314-Using-T4-templates-in-Entity-framework.html).

In the template, I changed `ICollection` to `List`, and added `[Serializable]` to entity types and complex types.

I also had to disable proxy type generation:

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)entities).ObjectContext.ContextOptions.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```