# ASP.NET Web Service Using Relational Database ADO.NET Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

So I am currently learning how to build a Web Service (ASMX) using ASP.NET to complete my homework. I am using SQL Server Database and ADO.NET for Data Model. Here is my database:
[image: ADO.NET Model Relation]

And here is the generated model

User.cs

```cs
public partial class User
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public User()
        {
            this.Posts = new HashSet<Post>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }
```

Post.cs

```cs
public partial class Post
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }

        public virtual User User { get; set; }
    }
```

I am trying to get the data from the WebService.asmx using something like this

```cs
[WebMethod]
        public List<Post> GetAllPosts()
        {
            using (var db = new DatabaseEntities())
            {
                return db.Posts.ToList();
            }
        }
```

When I run the service, it gives me this error:

> Cannot serialize member WebService.Models.User.Posts of type
>   System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[WebService.Models.Post,
>   WebService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
>   because it is an interface. Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please
>   review the stack trace for more information about the error and where
>   it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Cannot serialize
>   member WebService.Models.User.Posts of type
>   System.Collections.Generic.ICollection`1[[WebService.Models.Post,
>   WebService, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
>   because it is an interface.

I somewhat know that the error is caused by the relation between User and Post, but I don't fully understand why. Is there any good explanation on what happened and what is the best approach I can use to fix this?

Comment: If your curriculum is teaching you ASMX and EDMX, they're seriously behind the times. The industry has moved away from those technologies. You might want to rethink where you're getting your education from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your Post is a ICollection and you cannot serialize an interface. See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7502658/how-to-serialize-property-of-type-icollectiont-while-using-entity-framework) helps resolve.

Comment: It does works, but I wonder if there is any way other than changing the default generated model manually...